# How to create a new column made of a sequence without knowning the number of repetitions - data.table

Tags: r, data.table

my question is far from being a complex one but I didn't find the answer online. To put it simple, I would like to know how to create a new column and add a seq() to it. The problem is that I don't know **the number of repetitions that will be need**. I know you can specify the `rep` argument but what if you don't know what is the data in advance? Is there a way to do this with `data.table` ? :

```
data <- data[, new.col := seq(1,3,1)]
```

This is logically returning me the following error:

> Error in [.data.table(data, , :=(new.col, seq(1, 3, 1))) :
>   Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 13502 items of column 'new.col'.
>   The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the
>   LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep()
>   explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Here is an example of the data I currently have and the output I want:

```
current data

id  sexe
109   F
100   F 
157   M 
151   M 
160   M 
168   M



desired output

id  sexe new.col
109   F     1
100   F     2
157   M     3
151   M     1
160   M     2
168   M     3
```

I know it would work but I don't want to specify the the number of `rep` needs for the `seq()`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `length.out` argument of `rep`

```
df[, new.col := rep(1:3, length.out = .N)]

df
#     id sexe new.col
# 1: 109    F       1
# 2: 100    F       2
# 3: 157    M       3
# 4: 151    M       1
# 5: 160    M       2
# 6: 168    M       3
```

You can also use `rep_len`

```
df[, new.col := rep_len(1:3, .N)]
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
df$new.col <- rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(df))
```